# Restrict scope of global variable inside one file in C

Tags: c, scope

I have two `.c` files, for example `mylib.c` and `main.c` and one header file `mylib.h`. Main idea is to make global static array, which size I can define from `main.c`, but it can be accessible from `mylib.c` and can NOT be accessible in `main.c`. The code, that I have at the moment:

mylib.c:

```c
#define _MYLIB_C_
#include "mylib.h"

extern char my_array[];

void test()
{
    // Doing something with my_array...
}
```

main.c:

```c
#define MY_ARRAY_SIZE 128
#include "mylib.h"

void main()
{
    test();
}
```

mylib.h:

```c
#ifndef _MYLIB_H_
#define _MYLIB_H_

void test();

#ifndef _MYLIB_C_

char my_array[MY_ARRAY_SIZE];

#endif /* _MYLIB_C_ */
#endif /* _MYLIB_H_ */
```

So, question is: "Can I restrict scope of `my_array` to make it invisible inside `main.c`?"

Comment: I'm not sure what your situation is, but wouldn't it be better to have a function that dynamically allocates the array so the array doesn't need to be accessible from `main.c`?

Comment: Move your array to a header which is only in main.c included.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that, but I can't use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Anyway, if it's your code just don't use that variable. If it's meant to be in something like a library, put an underscore before the name and don't document its existence.

Comment: "global static array" is like saying "square-shaped circle".

Comment: @Lundin So it's a wrestling ring.  :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca so, I suppose, that is the only way... I will put underscore before the name of the array an hope that user of library will read documentation and will not do strange things.

Comment: @AleksandrNagaev basically, yes. It's well understood by developers that if you use undocumented features you are on your own. You may go as far as explicitly saying "don't directly use that variable". Think about python, for example, which has very little information hiding facilities. Every python programmer knows that they're not supposed to toy with class members that start with `_`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make `my_array` visible only in mylib.c, then you need to define it as `static` in that file and not put anything in the header file.

So mylib.c should contain:

```
static char my_array[MY_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

And mylib.h should not list this variable at all.  Not that this means that `MY_ARRAY_SIZE` needs to be visible in mylib.c.

Comment: Of course, `static` specifier limit visibility of variable only by file scope. But there is absolutely no way to make `MY_ARRAY_SIZE` visible in `mylib.c` because it is just integer literal defined by preprocessor and it must be defined in `main.c`.

Comment: @AleksandrNagaev Then you have no choice: you **must** use dynamic allocation.  You'll need to expose a function in mylib.c that takes the size and allocates space for the array.

Comment: @AleksandrNagaev Alternately,  put `MY_ARRAY_SIZE` in a separate header file and include that in both mylib.c and main.c, assuming you can compile them together.

Comment: `mylib.c` will be compiled in static library and `mylib.h` must provide interface to use it. `MY_ARRAY_SIZE` is just one parameter that I want to user can define. I can't use dynamic allocation because I want that library to be used in different types of microcontrollers with very limited amount of memory. And actually, `MY_ARRAY SIZE` always known at compile-time, so it's not necessary to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @AleksandrNagaev Then you need to give it some fixed size that will be big enough for anyone that might want to use it.

Comment: @AleksandrNagaev Your only other option would be to create the array in the user program and pass it to any library function that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Any file will easily be able to declare this variable and use it.

Answer (score 0):

add `extern yourGlobal` in your header, then just declare yourGlobal in one of the file (it's been a while since i last used it, but look for the keyword 'extern' in any case) so you'll be able to use in any file using the header.
 Declare another header whitout to restrict it

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround:

```c
#ifndef _MYLIB_H_
#define _MYLIB_H_

void test();

#ifndef _MYLIB_C_

char my_array[MY_ARRAY_SIZE];
#define my_array 0

#endif /* _MYLIB_C_ */
#endif /* _MYLIB_H_ */
```

I just redefine name of array by zero after it declaration. So, if somebody try to use that name in `main.c` he is obviously get a compiler error. But in `mylib.c` still everything is OK. It's better than nothing.